# I need a k2 module to show user "unread" articles

Tags: k2

I have extensivly looked for a k2 module that could show logged user only unread articles and havent found anything yet;

The idea is that when the user logges in, the module will show only unread articles... if the user read the article in any moment, the module should no longer show it inside this module... the module should show artile title, intro text, intro image, category, creation/modification date at least....

I haven't find anything that does this? Is there something like this? if not, could somebody develope it?

Comment: I've never heard of an existing module like that, someone could develop it for sure but you might need a plugin as well that actually detects when the logged user reads the article.

Comment: I've never heard of anything like this as well, but it is a great idea. This would provide very personalized content, which is great. @Shaz is right that you need a plugin to record when the user reads an item. Nice idea!

Comment: I'm curious to know if Joomla actually tracks that data on the user or if it just tracks that the page has been viewed x amount of times by anyone.

Comment: @BrianPeat - Joomla only tracks page hits, not user specific level like this.

Comment: Is it something a plugin could track in its own tables if someone built it?

Comment: @BrianPeat yes that would be possible and actually not very hard to do. One could just record the user ID, component & content ID on each hit which would give some really nice stats of how users are using the site as well as giving you the option of creating said module. Am actually considering making a plugin like that as it would be useful information to have on my sites too...